# Wpf Resource: "Unknown Build Error, 'Path cannot be null..."

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The following is a snippet from a xaml defining a DataGrid in a Control, defining a template selector.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <selector:CurrencyColorSelector x:Key="currencyColorSelector">
        <selector:CurrencyColorSelector.NegativeTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Balance, StringFormat=n}" Background="Red"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </selector:CurrencyColorSelector.NegativeTemplate>
        <selector:CurrencyColorSelector.NormalTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Balance, StringFormat=n}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </selector:CurrencyColorSelector.NormalTemplate>
    </selector:CurrencyColorSelector>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Now, an error is thrown: "Unknown build error, 'Path cannot be null. Parameter name: path Line 27 Position 79.'" (Compiler or xaml validation error).

**Edit**

After a reboot of Visual Studio 2010 I get the following:

> The tag 'CurrencyColorSelector' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:EveTrader.Wpf.Selectors;assembly=EveTrader.Wpf'. Line 27 Position 18.

Which makes it even weirder, as I even have intelisense for the class.

---

I have no idea where this Path comes from, neither does my example show anything of it. If you doubleclick the error, it points to the end of `<selector:CurrencyColorSelector x:Key="currencyColorSelector">` (line 27).

Did anybody encounter such a problem and has a solution for it? The example was from here: http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html (Row Details depending on the type of data)

**Clarification**

This is under .net 4.0. The Problem has to do with the CurrencyColorSelector, as the Templates themselves work fine if used in the DataGridTemplateColumn on their own. `CurrencyColorSelector` derives from `DataTemplateSelector`.

**CurrencyColorSelector**

```
namespace EveTrader.Wpf.Selectors
{
    public class CurrencyColorSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate NegativeTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate NormalTemplate { get; set; }

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            var data = item as DisplayWallets;

            if (data == null)
                return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);

            if (data.Balance < 0m)
                return NegativeTemplate;
            return NormalTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

**DisplayWallets**

```
public class DisplayWallets
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
```

**Xaml selector definition**

```
<UserControl x:Class="EveTrader.Wpf.WalletsView"
             xmlns:selector="clr-namespace:EveTrader.Wpf.Selectors;assembly=EveTrader.Wpf">
```

Comment: Can you post the code for currencyselector and what `selector:` is defined to in your XAML file?

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with a reference to the `EveTrader.Wpf` needing to be added to the XAML project? Perhaps they go to different outputput folders and if there is not reference, it might fail at runtime. Still doesn't explain the design-time error though.

Comment: Have you considered reporting this to the VS support team? It seems bizarre and unexplainable to warrant being a bug in Visual Studio itself.

Comment: Igor: EveTrader.Wpf is the assembly/project the xaml resides in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it. The problem was the definition of selector:

`xmlns:selector="clr-namespace:EveTrader.Wpf.Selectors;assembly=EveTrader.Wpf"`.

As the type CurrencyColorSelector resides in the EveTrader.Wpf assembly, this definition created a circular reference which created the error - the compiler tried to compile the assembly EveTrader.Wpf, but because of the defition of `selector`, it tried to create EveTrader.Wpf first. This continued ad nauseam. The fix is simple: remove the assembly definition: `xmlns:selector="clr-namespace:EveTrader.Wpf.Selectors"`.

I fixed this problem after some hours of sleep after working through the night, which proves again, sleep is needed. Thanks for the help Igor anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Path in Binding is usually the bit that follows the word Binding.

```
{Binding MyCustomText}
          ^
          |
        Binding

<!--OR-->

{Binding Path=MyCustomText}
               ^
               |
             Binding
```

<strike>This error means there is something wrong with the binding.</strike>

`StringFormat` Binding property was introduced in a service pack to .NET 3.5 from memory. A good way to check if your version of WPF supports `StringFormat` is to see if class `BindingBase` has a property `StringFormat`.

With updated informatin I got nothing :( Looks like it should work.

Comment: I'm using .net 4.0. Changing the Binding to Path= didn't change anything. Besides, the problem only started to appear with the resource - using the StringFormat in other places worked like a charm.

Comment: Right, must be something else then.

Comment: I fixed it, the solution is surprisingly simple.